# Link binance balance and coingecko info

Tags: binance, cryptocurrency, coingecko

Using `node-binance-api` package and method `balance` i get a map where the key is a symbol and value my current balance. Next, I would like to fetch some information from CoinGecko. So, firstly I get coins list by calling this endpoint https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3#/coins/get_coins_list which return me an array of object with fields `id`, `symbol` and `name`. Now I try to find coingecko coins id using filter by `symbol`. However, some coins have the same symbol (ada, acm, etc...)

```
{
    "id" : "ac-milan-fan-token",
    "symbol" : "acm",
    "name" : "AC Milan Fan Token",
}

{
    "id" : "actinium",
    "symbol" : "acm",
    "name" : "Actinium",
}
```

Is there any way to distinguish them? My main goal to have 1 view for all exchanges I have (binance, gate, metamask ..etc) and show proper information

Answer (score 2):

Since the `symbol` is not an unique identifier in your dataset, you'll need to make an unique ID for each currency. Then you'll need to assign (either manually or automatically) the data to the current ID.

After you've build a table of unique IDs and a relation of each exchange ID to the currency IDs, you can just watch for changes: Remove the relations that aren't valid anymore, add new valid relations, and of course assign the newly added currencies to their correct IDs.

Example - you might end up with a list like this:

**Currencies**

| ID | Symbol | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BTC | Bitcoin |
| 2 | ACM | AC Milan Fan Token |
| 3 | ACM | Actinium |

**Exchanges**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Binance |
| 2 | Coingecko |

**Currencies to Exchanges**

| ID Currency | ID Exchange | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Bitcoin on Binance |
| 1 | 2 | Bitcoin on Coingecko |
| 2 | 2 | AC Milan Fan Token on Coingecko |
| 3 | 1 | Actinium on Binance |
| 3 | 2 | Actinium on Coingecko |

---

You'll basically need to do a very similar thing as the team behind the CoinMarketCap API is doing.

- `/v1/cryptocurrency/map` ([docs](https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyInfo))

  Each currency has a CMC-wide unique ID. So they can have multiple currencies with the same symbol, but they are differentiated by an ID.
- `/v1/cryptocurrency/market-pairs/latest` ([docs](https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyMarketpairsLatest))

  They have a step between the currency-to-exchange relation, that you're aiming to create, in the form of a "market pair ID". Example: "BTC/USD" pair has always CMC-wide ID 1, across all exchanges.
- `/v1/exchange/market-pairs/latest` ([docs](https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1ExchangeMarketpairsLatest))

  Finally each exchange has a relation to market pair IDs. So if exchange ID 123 and exchange ID 456 both have a "BTC/USD" pair, they both have a relation to the pair ID 1.

---

It's not an easy thing and it requires some amount of resources: Manual tagging, as well as validating, finetunning and maitaining your algorithms (because the input data structure keeps changing) to save as much data from all different sources automatically with as few mistakes as possible.

As you can see on the CMC example, it's achieveable. But it does require a much higher scope than a StackOverflow answer, so I hope this gives you at least a rough idea of what all you need to do in order to achieve the desired result.